# Why isn't the CSS file showing up?

Tags: html, css

I've double checked my syntax for linking the CSS file in the  of my HTML file, and it all looks correct to me. And when I view the page source of my HTML page, it does indeed to be linking correctly to the CSS page. But none of the styling seems to be showing up. I'm fairly certain that the linking of the CSS file is fine, but I can't understand why none of the changes are appearing.

HTML FILE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--title to appear on the tab of the browser-->
    <title>Midterm: Hangman</title>

    <!--linking a CSS style sheet for the page--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="hangman.css">

    <!--running the hangman game-->
    <script src="hangman.js"></script>
</head>

<!--run the main function from the javascript file when page is loaded-->
<body onload="javascript:hideWord()">
    <!--adding a title that will appear on the webpage-->
    <h1>Hangman</h1>

    <!--create a text box, restrict to only one letter being able to be typed, create placeholder text-->
    <input id="guessedLetter" type="text" maxlength="1" minlength="1" placeholder="Guess a letter" />

    <!--create a button to submit guessed letter and run the compareLetter function when clicked-->
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:compareLetter()">Guess!</button>


    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:hideWord()">Restart</button>

    <!--underscores to hide the word that the player is guessing-->
    <div id="hiddenWord"></div>

    <!--a counter to keep track of number of player attempts-->
    <p id="counter"></p>

    <!--add instructions for the player-->
    <h2>Instructions</h2>
    <p>Put some instructions here!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS FILE:

```
body {
    background: #2C2A30;
}

button[type=button] {
    background: #D94C47;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #D94C47;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

button[type=button]:hover {
    background: #FF7A61;
    border: 1px solid #FF7A61;
    color: #2C2A30;
}
```

SCREENSHOT OF CHROME DEVELOPER TOOL:
[image]

SCREENSHOT OF FOLDER STRUCTURE:
[image]

Comment: What does your browser's Developer Tools window's Network tab say?

Comment: Where is the css file in relation to the html file?

Comment: `onclick="javascript:compareLetter()">` won't work. Only use the `javascript:` URI scheme in `href=""`, for `onclick` you can put script there directly: `onclick="compareLetter()"`.

Comment: Is the CSS file in the same directory as this HTML file? And can you post the CSS?

Comment: @Dai When I open the tool, it shows the html and javascript page, but I can't see the CSS file in the folder, even though it is all in the same folder on my computer.

Comment: @Colin They're all in a folder called hangman on my Desktop.

Comment: @JustinLardinois Sure! I'll add that on.

Comment: Are you doing this in Visual Studio?

Comment: @user2903379 Nope, I'm using Sublime Text and Chrome (to view the page).

Comment: @Karen can you provide a screenshot of your folder structure within Sublime?

Comment: @user2903379 Do you mean the folder that I made on my Desktop with Sublime? And I'll also post what I see in my Developer Tool on Chrome (strangely the CSS file doesn't seem to be showing up there either)

Comment: Yes please, unless there is a folder structure tree that is shown in subline (I dont use sublime so I dont know). And it would make sense that tool isnt showing the css file. Its actually not strange at all. I suspect the link isnt right, but ill see when when the file is uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="type/css" href="hangman.css">
```

should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hangman.css">
```

Note the `type` --> `text`.

Additionally, in HTML5 you don't need the `type` attribute at all, so you can just have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hangman.css">
```

Comment: Good spot! I didnt notice that

Comment: AH! Oh wow...thank you so much! Oh the headaches a small typo can create haha

Comment: Haha, happens to all of us!

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `<link rel="stylesheet" href="hangman.css">`.

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS page is linking to the html page, and you're not seeing updates, it's possible that this is a cashing issue. In Google Chrome, right click on the page and click 'Inspect'. THEN, wiith the inspector open, navigate to the top of the page near the address bar and right click on the refresh icon. Then select 'Empty cache and Hard Reload'.

Comment: Hmm no luck :( Still appears to be ignoring the CSS sheet

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by ignoring the style sheet?

Comment: None of the changes are appearing, like background color etc. However, when I go to view the page source, I can see that it is linking correctly to the CSS file.

Comment: So, there is no styles at all from the stylesheet?

Comment: Yes. It's just not showing up on the HTML page, but the files seem to be linking correctly.